# img src attribute changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of blank images, which on click I'd like to change.
So, I'm creating a table with:

```
table_string = "<center><table border=1>";
for( i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ )
{
    table_string += "<tr>";
    for( j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ )
    {
        table_string += "<td><img name=image"+i+"_"+j+" src=games/graphics/atoms/blank.jpg onclick='OnClick("+i+","+j+")'></td>";
    }
    table_string+="</tr>";
}
table_string+= "</table></center>";
$("#atoms_board").append(table_string); //appending the html code to atoms_board div,
```

And now the OnClick function in which im trying to change the src attribute:

```
function OnClick( i, j )
{
    $('input[name=image"+i+"_"+j+"]').attr('src');
}
```

My problem is that function OnClick doesn't change the img's src ;/. I saw here many similiar problems, but everywhere i found only this answer. Any help appreciated : }.

Comment: The nesting of single and double quotes in this looks suspicious to say the least `$('input[name=image"+i+"_"+j+"]')`. Did you step through it in the JavaScript debugger of your browser?

Comment: Did you try to replace " by ' like this : 'input[name=image'+i+'_'+j+']' ?

Comment: I just changed the quoting to correct as Alex Wayne showed, but with no effect.

Comment: NITPICK: center elements are deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a reference to itself using "this".

```
onclick="OnClick(this)"


OnClick function(element) {
      alert(element.src)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, alert returns correct image src path, but still with using 'element' instead of input[name=image"+i+"_"+j+"] it doesn't work ; /.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything either: $('input[name=image"+i+"_"+j+"]').attr('src'); It neither sets nor reads a value.

Comment: oh i forgot to paste it, im terribly sorry;] it looks like this:
$("input[name=image"+i+"_"+j+"]").attr('src','games/graphics/atoms/red1.jpg');

Comment: Without seeing a working example, I really have no advice to offer.

Comment: Thanks, i just needed to edit passing the argument after tring Alex's method thank you for staying with me : ]

Answer (score 3):

Note the syntax highlighting in the bottom snippet. See how it's all one color? You are encoding your logic into the string. This means you string is this:

```
'input[name=image"+i+"_"+j+"]'
```

Instead of this:

```
'input[name=image1_2]'
```

Try:

```
$("input[name=image"+i+"_"+j+"]").attr('src');
//^ big quote                  ^ big quote
```

See how the variable turn black in the syntax highlighting now? That means they are no longer considered literally part of the string.

If you aren't using an editor with syntax highlighting, I highly suggest you find one. They help you find this sort of problem.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to be a little bit more careful with quotes in the future. I re-writed the line, filled the src path, but it didnt change the situation ; /.

Comment: Well, then you likely have more than one problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue in your code. Modify it to

```
function OnClick( i, j )
{
    $('input[name=image'+i+'_'+j+']').attr('src');
}
```